# MySQL Database Connection Failed in Anypoint studio

Tags: mysql, jdbc, mulesoft, anypoint-studio

I'm trying to set a Database configuration in Anypoint Studio 7.14.0 in order to connect to the following MySQL database:

- **host** : mudb.learn.mulesoft.com
- **port** : 3306
- **user** : mule
- **password** : mule
- **database** : training

but I keep receiving the following Connection error:
[image]

Can someone help me? I have been struggling for hours.

**NOTE** : The JDBC Driver for MySQL that I'm using is described in the following Maven dependency added to my Mule project[image]

Comment: You should *never* share real access information and credentials publicly and even less so for a database that is Internet accessible. Looks that it is not even your own database. Also please provide logs and configurations as text information not screenshots, as explained in Stackoverflow Help Center https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question. You should also share the database connector configuration, masking confidential details.

Comment: Have you tested if there is connectivity to the host and port?

Comment: @aled I know, I just did it because this is a free course available for anyone and so the database is public, but thanks for the warning, I'll remember it for later issues. About the connectivity to the host and port, I tried to ping the server and I got no response, so maybe the server is down but also can be related to the firewall my network was using when I raised the issue.

Comment: I can connect to the host and port so it may be a problem in your network connectivity.